# Get Return Value from IronPython into Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ironpython

I am trying to execute a IronPython Script from Python 3.4.
I Have function in IronPython script which returns a dictionary and I want to get that dictionary into python 3.4 area.

I am using Subprocess.call to run IronPy script from Python 3.4

So, I want to know that is there any way to get return value of external (IronPy) program into python 3.4 area.

Comment: IronPython *is* Python. Why do you need to call out to a separate process?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I'd assume he wants to call some .NET code, but he also wants to do some 3.x-specific stuff, and since there is no 3.x IronPython…

Comment: Right Perfectly said.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly return an object from a subprocess. The "return value" of a process is just a number from 0-127 (the number you pass to [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), or 0 if you just fall off the end of the program), which isn't very useful.

However, subprocesses *are* connected by pipes: if you just run the child with [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `call`, whatever bytes it writes to `stdout`, you can read.

So, if you can convert your data into a stream of bytes and back, then it's easy.

- If the data in the dict are all simple types (NoneType, bool, int, float, str, list, dict), encode it with `json`.
- Or, if they're all builtin/stdlib types and types defined in .py files that you share between CPython and IronPython, encode it with `pickle`.
- Or, if they're something you can represent as fixed C-like structures, you can use the `struct` or `ctypes` modules.
- etc.

---

For example:

```
# parent.py
import json
import subprocess

result = subprocess.check_output(['ironpython.exe', 'myironscript.py'],
                                 universal_newlines=True)
result_dict = json.loads(result)
print(result_dict["key"])
```

And:

```
# child.py
import json

def do_the_work():
    return {'key': 'value', 'other': 'stuff'}

result = do_the_work()
print json.dumps(result)
```

When you run this, it'll print out `value`.

(Because `json.dumps` defaults to escaping anything that's not pure ASCII, you can safely pass it as text rather than bytes. For most other formats, you'll want to use `sys.stdout.write` in the child instead of `print`, and leave the `universal_newlines=True` off the parent.)